# Redundant element names with complex/multiple xml namespaces in php Soap

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-namespaces, soap-client

I have another question related to this posted, but now that I'm trying to use SoapVar more directly, I see this is a different issue.
I'm working with the UPS Soap Rate quote webservice and they have multiple xml namespace XSD files that are used in a single rate request:

```
xmlns:common="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0"
xmlns:rate="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Rate/v1.1"
xmlns:upss="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0"
```

When building the data structure in php, it seems to assign them ns1, ns2 and ns3 respectively.

The problem seems to be occurring based on the fact that xmlns:common and xmlns:rate both have an identical datastructure named CodeDescriptionType. And of course, this is a generic type that they seem to use over and over again throughout both requests, and responses and even occasionally in the error messages they spit back, just under different element names.

The issue that I am have is that whether I build an object representation of the request or if I go section by section building each branch with distinct 'SoapVar' instances for each sub-branch naming the xml namespace specifically for each, as soon as I pass the data through the SoapClient (or more specifically __soapCall), PHP seems to fill in the namespaces with the ns1/ns2/ns3 and then mis-assigns the CodeDescriptionTypes as ns1 (common) when they should be ns2 (rate).

common.xsd: (relevant portion)

```
<xsd:complexType name="CodeDescriptionType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Code" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

RateWebServiceSchema.xsd: (relevant portion)

```
<xsd:complexType name="CodeDescriptionType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Code" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Depending on how I build the data, I get one of two results using the PHP tools. If I create it all as one big datastructure and pass it into __soapCall or via a SoapVar conversion first, I get the outer wrapper misnamed as well as the content (should be ns2):

```
        <ns1:PickupType>
            <ns1:Code>01</ns1:Code>
        </ns1:PickupType>
        <ns1:CustomerClassification>
            <ns1:Code>00</ns1:Code>
        </ns1:CustomerClassification>
```

If I try to explicitly create a SoapVar for anything using this element type or an inherited version of it, I end up with the inner portion mis-namespaced:

```
        <ns2:PickupType>
            <ns1:Code>01</ns1:Code>
        </ns2:PickupType>
        <ns2:CustomerClassification>
            <ns1:Code>00</ns1:Code>
        </ns2:CustomerClassification>
```

Does anyone know if there's a work around for this using the soap built-ins that would allow you to make sure it interprets the namespaces properly when assigning them in the xml it builds? My guess is the keys are conflicting when it's creating some kind of array or property list of the combined element definitions and only the common version remains in the final data used to build the xml. I don't see anything in the classmap docs to say if you can split them up via namespace.
The only way I've found to get the 'correct' output is to first generate a test to see how the namespaces are being 'renamed' by php (e.g. the ns1 for common and the ns2 for rate) and then manually build any CodeDescriptionTypes under the xmlns:rate namespace by hand before passing them into SoapVar:

```
/**
 * @param string $code
 * @param null|string $desc
 * @param string $elem
 * @return \SoapVar
 */
public static function getRaw($code, $desc=null, $elem='CodeDescription') {
    $xml = sprintf("<ns2:%s>", $elem);
    $xml .= sprintf("<ns2:Code>%s</ns2:Code>", $code);
    if(!empty($desc))
        $xml .= sprintf("<ns2:Description>%s</ns2:Description>", $desc);
    $xml .= sprintf("</ns2:%s>", $elem);
    return new \SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML, $elem);
}
```

Then if I wanted to define the two elements above as part of my bigger data structure, I'd do something like:

```
    // pickup information
    $req->PickupType = Soap\rate\CodeDescriptionType::getRaw("01", null, 'PickupType');

    // customer classification
    $req->CustomerClassification = Soap\rate\CodeDescriptionType::getRaw("00", null, 'CustomerClassification');
```

This is an ugly solution as it is bound to break if for any reason the xsd or wsdl files should change and/or php handling of the namespaces is modified such that the rate namespace no longer ends up being 'ns2'. Any suggestions?